# How to bind a Singleton to Python in pybind across libraries

Tags: python, c++, cmake, singleton, pybind11

I have a Singleton defined in C++ that I want to expose to Python. Python seems to create a new instance of the Singleton no matter how I bind it. My main code is in a core library, which the Python module is also linked to.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(pybind-singleton)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0148 NEW)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(pybind11 CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development REQUIRED)

add_library(my_lib SHARED
    src/Singleton.cpp
)

message(STATUS "Python include dirs: " ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(STATUS "pybind include dirs: " ${pybind11_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_include_directories(my_lib PUBLIC include ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${pybind11_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(my_lib PUBLIC Python3::Python)

pybind11_add_module(my_module src/binding.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_module PUBLIC my_lib)


add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC my_lib)
```

```cpp
class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton &GetInstance()
    {
        static Singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }

    Singleton(Singleton const &) = delete;
    void operator=(Singleton const &) = delete;
    std::string test;

    void Init();

    void PrintTest();

private:
    Singleton(){};
};
```

```cpp
namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(my_module, m)
{
    py::class_<Singleton>(m, "Singleton")
        .def_static(
            "print_test", []()
            { Singleton::GetInstance().PrintTest(); },
            py::return_value_policy::reference)
        .def_static(
            "get_test_val", []()
            { 
                Singleton &singleton = Singleton::GetInstance();
                return singleton.test; },
            py::return_value_policy::reference)
        .def_static(
            "get_instance", &Singleton::GetInstance, py::return_value_policy::reference)
        .def_readwrite("test", &Singleton::test);
}
```

```py
from my_module import Singleton

print('Accessing Singleton...')

test_val = Singleton.get_test_val()
print('Test val:', test_val if test_val != '' else 'None')

print('--')
Singleton.print_test()

print('--')
instance = Singleton.get_instance()
print(instance)
print(instance.test)
instance.test = 'Python\'s instance'
print(instance.test)
instance.print_test()
```

```
% ./pybind-singleton 
Instancing Singleton...
/Users/jordan/dev/pybind-singleton/src/Singleton.cpp: 12

/Users/jordan/dev/pybind-singleton/src/Singleton.cpp: 12
C++'s instance
------------
Running init.py
Accessing Singleton...
Test val: None
--
/Users/jordan/dev/pybind-singleton/src/Singleton.cpp: 12

--
<my_module.Singleton object at 0x1024b9fb0>

Python's instance
/Users/jordan/dev/pybind-singleton/src/Singleton.cpp: 12
Python's instance
```

I've made up a minimal example in this repo; some of the code has been omitted from above for brevity: https://github.com/jordanlevy96/pybind-singleton